# Girl taken from her village and trained in magic in a tower

Tags: story-identification, novel

There's a book about a girl who's taken from her village and is trained under a magic person (?) while being away from her home (and living in a tower?)
I think it's a one word title and I know the cover has the girl holding a flower or magic or something. It's a beige-ish cover and a fantasy-like font. I'd know the cover when I saw it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Answer (score 7):

*Uprooted* by Naomi Novik fits both the plot and cover description.

From [the Wikipedia recap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uprooted_(novel)):

[image: Cover of Uprooted]

> Agnieszka lives in the village of Dvernik in the kingdom of Polnya. Every ten years the local wizard ("the Dragon") collects one teenage girl as payment for protecting the local valley from the magical forest (the Wood) that borders it. Despite being born in a tribute year, Agnieszka does not fear being taken, as the Dragon only chooses the best and brightest girls and she is clumsy and slovenly – unlike her beautiful friend Kasia, who has been groomed to be selected. But the Dragon picks Agnieszka to take to his tower instead.

Comment: Well-found! Was it one you were familiar with already?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yep - it was the first thing that came to mind for "girl leaves village to learn magic in a tower", then re-checking the cover confirmed it.